# Why this image link not showing up in UIimageView in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard

Why this image link not showing up in UIimageView in ios ?

```
var url = URL(string: "https://bill.ps/uploads/32065621a012e53f749c15b0a8468d71swift_file5486.png")
```

Code

```
func fetchImage(_ photoURL: URL?) { 
    guard let imageURL = photoURL else { return } 
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { 
        do { 
            let imageData: Data = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL) 
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                print(image)
            } 
        } catch { 
            print("Unable to load data: (error)")
        } 
    } 
}
```

[Image Link](https://bill.ps/uploads/32065621a012e53f749c15b0a8468d71swift_file5486.png)

Comment: Show complete code

Comment: its normal process for fetching data image

Comment: I pasted the code from this comment into your question, you should add code directly to the question not in comments.

Comment: can you try using the KingFisher pod?

Comment: i try KingFisher , image not appear also , uiimageView white @Menaim

Comment: Code is fine. I tried to extract EXIF info on http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi. But it's not a valid image URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the issue with backend developer , its related to WAF header on api server .

WAF block requests with missing in header.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the image itself not in the link or in your code, I've tried the same image and It's not appearing at all in many cases, but at the same time another image appeared, if you can, try to change it and it will work, I even downloaded it and tried to put it manually in the assets file but doesn't work as well, check the images below:

1- Adding the image locally in the assets
[image]

2- the image isn't appearing in the running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really use [`URLSessionDownloadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloadtask) for these things.

Anyway, the image link seems to be working, so there should not be any issue in fetching and displaying it.

Here are the things you can check -

1. Is the `print` inside `catch` being executed?
2. What is printed when you do `print(image)` after you receive data for it?
3. Is your `UIImageView` instance visible on screen and has non-zero `width` & `height` values at run time?

You must make sure about point #3 at run time using `View Hierarchy Debugger`.